# Table not displaying the Data

Tags: uitableview, odata, sapui5

Here i am using the table to display data from OData service. Rather displaying the data i could see blank but nothing, which means it says values are available. But it is not able to navigate to the path or display the values.

view.xml

```
<Table id="BoM" headerText="BOM Details"  class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" width="auto"
            items="{path : 'oModelBoM>/'
            }">

    <columns>
  <Column>
    <Label text="Material" />
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <Label text="Component" />
  </Column>
   <Column>
    <Label text="Brand" />
  </Column>
</columns>
<items>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
 <Text  text="{oModelBoM>Material}" />
 <Text text="{oModelBoM>Component}" />
 <Text text="{oModelBoM>Brand}" />
    </cells>
  </ColumnListItem>
</items>

</Table>
```

odata.js

```
getProductBoM : function(iNumber){
        var sNumber = iNumber.toString();
        while (sNumber.length < 18) {
            sNumber = "0" + sNumber
        }

        var vUriRead = "/ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM/
        var oResult;

        this.initODataModel( );

        this.oDataModel.read(vUriRead, null, null, false, function(oData, oResponse) {
            oResult = oData;
        }, function(oError) {
              jQuery.sap.log.error("OData-Error in function getProductBoM (EntityProductHead2BOM)");
              xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.displayRequestFailedMessage(oError);
        });

    return oResult;
}
```

controller.js

```
onInit : function() {

    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.handleRouteMatched, this);


    this.oModelBoM = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    this.getView().setModel(this.oModelBoM, "oModelBoM");

},

handleRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "ListDetailView") {
        var iNumber = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").number;


        //Call bom routine and set data

        var oBoM = xyz_homepage.xyz_homepage.src.odata.getProductBoM(iNumber);

        this.oModelBoM.setData(oBoM);
```

So the Uri tries to navigate to the path BOM but it is not happening, with the reference of the "12345" matching BOM should be displayed. Here i am using static reference as "12345", adding to same point could it be dynamic.

EDIT :

I get blank table but when i debug, the array is passing the value. Please find the screen shot below, but the values are not displaying on the table.

Thanks and Appreciated !!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wu7v.png)

Comment: what are you getting in oBoM?

Comment: I am getting the array values. which are 2 at the moment. So i could able to see the both the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am surprised that your `getProductBoM` function works. You are returning a variable `oResult`. The value of that variable is set in a callback, so in most cases AFTER it is returned.

It seems like you set the `async` parameter of the read function to false? Consider switching to Promises. Sync calls are deprecated (by browsers!).

Second, your model has the following structure:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        ...
    },
    "results": [
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

So I would change the line where you set the data to `this.oModelBoM.setData(oBoM.results);`

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the much needed help. Now i see where i was missing to pass the value.

Comment: But How can i call them dynamically, though i am calling static at the moment?

Comment: /ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM

Comment: Just... concatenate the string? `var vUriRead = "/ProductHeadSet('" + sNumber +  "')/ProductHead2BOM/`";

Answer (score 0):

Setting the table binding in the view as follows should work:

```
<Table id="BoM" items="{path : 'oModelBoM>**results**'}" >
```

However, the approach you follow is not really good. You can eliminate the usage of jsonModel and directly bind the OData Model on the success of the read.

In that case, your code should work as it is now without any changes.

Comment: But i had tried passing the Entity Set to the model but it displays "No Data".

Comment: items="{path:'oModelBoM>/ProductHead2BOM'}"

Comment: You need to see the model to the view in the success handler of your read call.